# Bash -- a sequence with specified length

Tags: bash

In R, a useful way to make a sequence a specified length is using `length.out`. For example

```
> for(i in seq(1,10,length.out=3)){print(i)}
[1] 1
[1] 5.5
[1] 10
```

Is there an analogue to `length.out` in bash?

Comment: Not in Bash, especially since Bash doesn't support floating points. With brace expansions, you can have arithmetic progression with given common difference, e.g., `echo {1..42..3}`. That's the closest you'll get with raw operators/builtins. You can code a function/script that uses external tools like `bc`, `awk`, `you-name-it` to get what you want. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of common techiques which are idiomatic in shell script (not just Bash). The shell itself is traditionally just a simple tool for building control structures and pipelines (the original Bourne shell had no support for built-in arithmetic -- even simple comparisons were delegated to a simple external tool, `test` aka `[` which however tends to be a built-in command in modern shells). Its power comes from external programs, so there is a lot of small programs which do simple things such as generate an endless stream of tokens, and pick the first `n` lines out of a stream (default `n`=10):

```
yes | head
```

Maybe add line numbers?

```
yes | nl | head
```

Reverse and sing a song?

```
yes | nl | head | tac |
while read num _; do
  printf '%i bottles of beer on the wall\n' "$num"
done
```

The other common idiom where this plethora of simple utilities is insufficient or inefficient is to extend the reach of the shell with various scripting languages -- traditionally, mainly `sed` and Awk; more recently, also Perl, Python, Ruby, etc (and at one point TCL was kind of popular, too). Here's the dates of the last ten days.

```
perl -e 'system(qq{date -d "$_ days ago" +%F}) for reverse 0..9'
```

Meanwhile, Bash in particular has been extended with fairly complete integer arithmetic, including a numeric `for` loop:

```
for ((i=10; i<=100; i+=55)); do
  d=${i%.}
  echo "$d.${i#$d}"
done
```